# How to get all groups user member of using Microstrategy Java SDK

Tags: java, microstrategy

Can anyone tell me how to get all the groups that a user member of using JAVA SDK. I have a user, I just want to fetch the list of groups in which the user is a member.

Please help.

Thanks,
Surodip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebUser.getAncestorGroups() will return all the groups a Microstrategy user is a member of. It will return WebUserGroup[]